# Run multiple times the same command in child_process in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

i'm currently facing a child_process problem which i can't find a way out.

I would like to run a simple command on the server using child_process.spawn() ou child_process.exec() :

```
let child = spawn('soffice', ['--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf:writer_pdf_Export', `${UPLOAD_DIR}/${file.bucket}/${file.filename}`, "--outdir", `${UPLOAD_DIR}/${file.bucket}`], { detached: true })
```

This is a task which could be triggered multiple times a minute by a variety of different users.

**Ok but what is it supposed to do ?**

This is taking any kind of Office File (Word, Excel), and converting it to pdf in the same folder.

**It is working fine with a single file at a time**

The problem occurs when I trigger it a second time before the first file is over, simply like this for example :

```
// File 1 Will be converted fine
let child = spawn('soffice', ['--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf:writer_pdf_Export', `${UPLOAD_DIR}/${file.bucket}/${file.filename}`, "--outdir", `${UPLOAD_DIR}/${file.bucket}`], { detached: true })

// File 2 will not be converted
let child = spawn('soffice', ['--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf:writer_pdf_Export', `${UPLOAD_DIR}/${file.bucket}/${file.filename}`, "--outdir", `${UPLOAD_DIR}/${file.bucket}`], { detached: true })
```

I already debugged the spawn to get all the outputs (stdout, stderr), the first process is working nicely, but the second is not outputting anything, but is closing with a code 0 (success).

My first impression is that the first process closes the second as well, as if they were "conflicting" (or simply being the same process for the CPU..).

**To make it short I need a way to spawn two separate instances of my command to make them work in parallel and independently of each other.**

Thanks by advance for your help.

Comment: Are you operating on the same file? Your example seems to show that the file names are identical.

Comment: Non i'm not, it's just for the example.